# Redraw matplotlib figure after updating Line2D properties through PyQt5 GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

In the following minimal-example GUI, I have a button and a plot window containing 2 lines. When the user clicks on the button, I want the linewidth of both lines to be changed, after which the plot should be redrawn.

When I click the button, I get a TypeError for the `draw()` command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "minimal_plot.py", line 55, in updatePlot
    self.sc.ax.draw()

TypeError: draw_wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'renderer'
```

**I never had to pass arguments to `draw()` before. What should I put there?**

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=100)
        self.ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # --- Define layout --- 
        layout1 = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton('', self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.updatePlot)
        layout1.addWidget(btn)

        # Plot section
        self.sc = MplCanvas(self)
        layout1.addWidget(self.sc)
        self.sc.setFixedHeight(600)
        self.sc.setFixedWidth(600)
        self.show()

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout1)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        # Create some lines
        self.sc.ax.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [10,1,20,3,40])
        self.sc.ax.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [9,0,19,2,39])

    def updatePlot(self):
       lines = self.sc.ax.get_lines()
       for i in range(len(lines)):
           lines[i].set_linewidth(4)

       self.sc.ax.draw()

    # Fix to make PyQt5 close correctly in Spyder    
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        QApplication.quit()       

# Run main code
app = QApplication.instance()
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Note: the code may differ slightly from a normal PyQt5 application because I run it in Spyder (that's why I invoke `app = Qapplication.instance()` instead of `app = Qapplication([])`. The `closeEvent()` definition can also be removed if one does not use Spyder.

Comment: I don't have PyQt5 installed so I can't test your MWE. However, in plain matplotlib `draw` is not a method of an axis but of a figure canvas (you wouldn't/couldn't specify a renderer on a per-axis basis). So never having made a Qt app, I would believe the correct command to be something like `self.sc.draw()` or `self.sc.ax.get_figure().canvas.draw()`.

Comment: Thanks, the `self.sc.draw()` indeed solved my problem!